# Why is the cross product is alternating?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, tensor-products

In the book *An introduction to manifolds* by Tu, Loring W, it says that

> The cross product $v\times w$ on $\mathbb R^3$ is alternating.

However in the definition of alternating, it says that

> A $k$-linear function $f:V^k\to\mathbb R$ is symmetric, if
> \begin{align*}
>     f\left(v_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots, v_{\sigma(k)}\right)=f\left(v_{1}, \ldots, v_{k}\right)
> \end{align*}
> for all permutations $\sigma\in S_k$; it is *alternating*, if
> \begin{align*}
>     f\left(v_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots, v_{\sigma(k)}\right)=(\operatorname{sgn} \sigma) f\left(v_{1}, \ldots, v_{k}\right)
> \end{align*}
> for all $\sigma\in S_k$.

[image]

However, I can't understand why the cross product is alternating. I think that the cross product $\times$ can be viewed as a function $\mathbb R^3\times \mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^3$, but not any function that maps to $\mathbb R$. So **why this is alternating**?

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to some, such as those who use screen readers. [Scanned pages from books are discouraged on SE network](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/155600/259305). Questions should contain sufficient context so that it is [answerable with the text alone](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1807/290189).

Comment: Okay, I have edited my post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct that using the given definition strictly, this doesn't make sense. However, there are a couple small changes in interpretation you could choose to make it work:

1. Extend the definition of a symmetric and alternating functions to apply to $k-$linear functions $V^k \to W$ for any vector space $W$. (You can use the same defining formulae.) In the case of the cross product, it's alternating in this sense simply because $u \times v = - v \times u.$
2. "Lower an index" on the cross product via the metric, i.e. consider $f(u,v,w) = (u \times v) \cdot w.$ This is then a 3-tensor on $\mathbb R^3$ that co-incides with the determinant.

Comment: Could you please expand on *via the metric*? Except from dot product, what can also be used to "Lower an index"?

Comment: @FFjet: in Riemannian geometry there's a generalization of the dot product called the Riemannian metric, and it is quite common to implicitly use it to change the type of a tensor. This is also known raising/lowering indices or as the [musical isomorphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_isomorphism).

If you're just beginning to learn differential geometry then I wouldn't worry too much about that (and I'm surprised Tu's book seems to assume you're familiar with the idea).

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3):

If you expand the definition of alternating to linear functions from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$, one has the following.

If $u$ and $v$ are linearly independant vectors, then $u\times v$ is defined to be the unique vector such that

- $\|u\times v\| = \|u\|\|v\||\sin(u,v)|$
- $u\times v$ is orthogonal to the plane generated by $u$ and $v$
- $(u,v,u\times v)$ is a positively oriented basis

Thus, if $(u,v,u\times v)$ is positively oriented, then $(v,u,u\times v)$ is negatively oriented. Hence, $(v,u,-(u\times v))$ is again positively oriented. The norm of $-(u\times v)$ is the good one, and it is orthogonal to $u$ and $v$. By uniqueness, $-(u\times v) = v\times v$.

As the cross product is bilinear, and the only permutations on a set of two elements are the identity or the transposition, it follows that the cross product is alternating.